# Can't load ngTable: 'Module 'ngTable' is not available!'

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to use ngTable in my app, and I do the following steps:

1) import ngTable css file

2) import ngTable.js file

3) add 'ngTable' to my angular.module('app', [xxx,yyy, 'ngTable'] like i've done for countless other libraries

4) copy paste example code in my controller (and inject 'ngTableParams')

Result: when I try to load the page I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngTable due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngTable' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have looked around but haven't found anything. I can't seem to understand why this wouldn't work... I would appreciate any input.

Comment: How did you do step 1 and 2?

Comment: Have you debugged the page in the browser to make sure the correct ngTable.js file is getting loaded?

Comment: It does get loaded, sorry I forgot to mention that. I do a console.log(at line 3 or so).

I just noticed though that before getting those errors, I actually get a "Cannot read property 'module' of null" on ng-table.js line 50 (var app = angular.module('ngTable', []);)

But this is straight from the ng-table.js I downloaded from github...

Comment: Ok sorry guys, i'm embarrassed, and have been banging my head on this for like 1 hour. It was due to the order in which I loaded the ngTable file ! :/

Comment: @ManuelMaestrini yeah that was pretty much why I asked for more info on step 1/2 ^^

Comment: @JimL I see... :/  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error till I start loading `ngTable` after loading angular itself.

Below is a snippet from my `index.html` to highlight the solution.

```
<script src="web/vendor/bower_components/angular-1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="web/vendor/bower_components/angular-1.7.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@3.0.1/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@3.0.1//bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```